# Can a protein kinase phosphorylate both a threonine and tyrosine residue?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

I know that some kinases can phosporylate both serine and threonine residues because of their structural similarities, but can such a kinase phosphorylate a tyrosine residue as well?

If not, then why?

Answer (score 2):

Ony a few protein kinases can phosphorylate all three amino acids — these are classified as [dual-specific kinases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-specificity_kinase) (EC 2.7.12.1). Examples are [APK1](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/F4HQQ0) from Arabidopsis or MEK kinases in mammals.

As with other enzymes, the residues at the substrate binding site determine which substrates can be accomodated there. Structures or [Ser- Thr-](http://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/152) and [Tyr](http://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/43)-kinases are available for inspection, should you wish to explore them.

Comment: Do you have a reference showing that the same catalytic domain in, for example, the MEK kinases phosphorylates both the Thr and Tyr simultaneously? I do know from working extensively with the MAPKs (Erk1/2 in particular) that the two residues can be under independent regulation. Part of that is obviously a function of different phosphatases, but I suspect there can be independent phosphorylation as well. Just not sure if it's by MEK1/2 or not.

Comment: Phosphorylation of MAP kinase by MEK at tyrosine 185 (pY185) and threonine 183 (pT183)...., ref: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21529/

Comment: I have edited your original answer because, although essentially correct (+1), it had a mistakes in the EC number, and the Kegg link was specifically for MAPKs, whereas the Wiki page considers dual-specificity kinases, specifically. I also put in a link to the structures. As you had done the heavy lifting, I don't want to steal your thunder by posting an alternative answer. Do revert as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Can I give you half the credit?

Comment: @Ashafix yes, I'm aware of the "classical" understanding of the pathway, I'm talking about what *really* goes on *in vivo*.

Comment: Well, I guess more qualified people with some real hands on experience should comment on that.

Comment: @Ashafix OK, just wondering if you knew...